# Facebook Login Button with show-faces="true" ignores registration-url

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

Not sure if this is a bug or if I'm missing something in the docs, but when I set show-faces="true" for the Facebook Login Button plugin on my website, it seems to stop paying attention to the registration-url parameter.

This one works as expected:

```
<fb:login-button registration-url="http://mysite.com/my_registration/"></fb:login-button>
```

Result:

- if user is not logged in to FB, will display "Login". When clicked,
  will prompt user to login. Once user logs in, if they are not registered with my site, will redirect to http://mysite.com/my_registration/. If they have already registered, will just close the auth dialog.
- if user is logged in to FB, but not registered with my site, will display "Register". When clicked, will immediately redirect to http://mysite.com/my_registration.
- if user is logged in to FB and already registered, will display "Login" but won't do anything when clicked.

All of this is fine and good. But, when I add show-faces="true" like so:

```
<fb:login-button registration-url="mysite.com/my_registration" show-faces="true"></fb:login-button>
```

Result:

- the faces show up, so that's good. However...
- if user is not logged in to FB, will display "Login". When clicked, will prompt user to login. Once user logs in, if they are not yet registered with my site, it will register them, but it **will not redirect** to the url specified by registration-url.
- if user is logged in to FB, but not registered with my site, will display "Login" (instead of "Register" like the example above). When clicked, again, **does not redirect** to the registraiton-url.
- if user is logged in to FB and already registered, it will show the faces, but it will not display the login button.

I haven't been able to find anything to explain the behavior. Anybody got any ideas or links? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to get it out the way, does specifying 1 instead of "true" do anything? No quotes.

Comment: I think it may have to do with the fact that when show-faces="true", an iframe is used for rendering, whereas when show-faces is not set, it's just XFBML and HTML. Thus, DOM events triggered inside the iframe (when show-faces="true") are unable to redirect the parent window. Can someone confirm/deny this hypothesis?

In any event, I still cannot find any docs on using registration-url and show-faces params together.

Comment: DOM events are allowed to trickle up through frames with mismatching URL's depending on your security level. For me, it shows a "Warning" in the JS console.

Comment: Still haven't found an answer to this, however, I simply started using the Facepile plugin which accomplishes what we are looking for.